# What does xUnit compatibility entail?

Tags: mocha.js, xunit

I was researching unit testing frameworks and the Wikipedia list has a column which lists whether a framework is considered the "xUnit type" or "compatible".  Mocha was listed as **not** being of the "xUnit type" – why?  What are the core features of the xUnit family?

Answer (score 0):

XUnit frameworks share the following concepts:

- Test runner - the program that runs the tests
- Test case - Where all tests inherit from
- Test fixture - the state needed to run the tests
- Test suites - tests that share the same fixture
- Assertion - the function that verifies the state of the test
- Test formatter - shows the results un one or more formats. This is a bit tricky, since the formats are not always the same. For example, [Inria's page](http://reflex.gforge.inria.fr/xunit.html#xunitReport) specifies the xml tags as **test-case** and **test-suite**. JUnit, on the other hand, uses **testcase** and **testsuite**.

You can think of XUnit frameworks as *Unit... where the * is replaced by the language (e.g., JUnit for Java).

What's very tricky is that XUnit.net is different from XUnit. XUnit.net is a framework on itself that also incorporates these aforementioned concepts. The XML output format uses different tags though... such as **assembly**, **class**, etc. It can get very confusing when googling for issues.